# Google Sheets: Automate Hidden Rows For Empty Cells

Tags: google-sheets, hide, cell, zero, invoice

I'm importing information into a Google Sheet that I'm hoping to print as a delivery list invoice.

The code below allows items marked "0" in Column H to disappear off the invoice, allowing the final product to appear cleaner.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the "Hide Row" function trigger for empty cells, so I don't have to manually enter in 0's.

As far as I can tell, the Filter function won't work because it won't update "OnEdit", only manually. I plan to repeat this for many sheets (one per customer) and require it to be automatic.

This is the code I have so far.

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('BELLTOWN');
s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
s.getRange('H:H')
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
            .charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(i + 1)
    });
}
function getNote(cell) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getComment();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()

to

if (r[0] == '' && r[0].toString()